# Using ggplot2 within map(), how to refer objects in formula of sec_axis()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I created graphs of ggplot2 using `map()`. I want to create second y-axis referring other objects, but object names in formula of `sec_axis()` aren't parsed within `map()`. How to refer other objects in formula of `sec_axis()`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is an example code and the outputs:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
d <- data_frame(n = sample(500:1000, 15), 
                group = letters[rep(1:5, 3)],
                year = rep(2011:2013, each = 5)) %>% 
  nest(-year)

d <- d %>% 
  mutate(
    gg1 = map2(data, year, ~ {
      total <- sum(.x$n)
      ggplot(.x, aes(x = group, y = n)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        ggtitle(paste0("year = ", .y, "; total = ", total))  # no problem
    }),
    gg2 = map2(data, year, ~ {
      total <- sum(.x$n)
      ggplot(.x, aes(x = group, y = n)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        ggtitle(paste0("year = ", .y, "; total = ", total)) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./total))   # problem line
    }))

d$gg1[[1]]   # run
d$gg2[[1]]   # Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : object 'total' not found
```

[image]

Comment: You need to refer to the variable explicitly:  `~ ./data$total`. however this brings up an entirely new error. R thinks you are subsetting a function called `data` when you are referring to the object `data` inside `d`. Because tibble automatically calls it `data` there isn't much to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response. I noticed that `formula()` can gives a formula and parsed object to `sec_axis()` within `map2()`. (this method doesn't solves the problem within `map()`, I think this is because `.` isn't explicit in `map()`)

```
d <- d %>% 
  mutate(
    gg2 = map2(data, year, ~ {
      total <- sum(.x$n)
      ggplot(.x, aes(x = group, y = n)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        ggtitle(paste0("year = ", .y, "; total = ", total)) +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(formula(paste0(" ~ ./", total))))
    }),
    gg3 = map(data, ~ {
      total <- sum(.x$n)
      ggplot(.x, aes(x = group, y = n)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(formula(paste0(" ~ ./", total))))
    }))

d$gg2[[1]]  # run
d$gg3[[1]]  # Error in as.list.environment(x, all.names = TRUE) : 
            #  the ... list does not contain 2 elements
```

[image]